# SpringBoot OAuth2 Customizing Exception Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

can someone help me with customizing SpringBoot 2 OAuth 2.0's Exception responses? Basically I need following exception responses into some custom application-specific response.

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired: sdfhjkudxnkjjkJJHGhgnbHnmbhJGJH"
}

{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-29T11:30:47.045+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/testf"
}
```

Something like

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Really looking forward
Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

You may do it for 403 while configuring HttpSecurity:

```
.exceptionHandling()     
.accessDeniedHandler(myCoolAccessDeniedHandler())
```

Like specified in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html)

Other two may be catched and handled by some ExceptionHandler you may define:

```
public class MyExceptionHandlingController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements ErrorController
```